# How to inlude files of sub-repository in main repository?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, git-submodules, mercurial-subrepos

Basically I want to reproduce [this method](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb) with Mercurial. 
I don't want to have actual sub-repository, I just want manage files of sub-repo as files of my main project and main repository, and at the same time have `.hg` directory for this fake sub-repo and be able to perform all Mercurial operations fo it.
Problem here is how to setup Mercurial to ignore all subrepositories and treat their files just as normal files.

Comment: Mercurial actively forbids that, and for a good reason: it would create an ambiguous revision manifest, which is what the subrepo feature specifically wants to avoid. In addition, it would store the same information twice. Perhaps you mean nested repository instead of subrepos?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "fake subrepo", you can have natural **nested repository** (repository in subdirectory of working dir, unrelated to outer repo) - and any file below nested repo-dir can belong to any of "outer" repository.
Just don't forget in @master-repo" hgignore all `.hg` folders in subdirs (*you don't need version nested repository per-se*). Not tested, but seems as viable way